# What is the difference between weak topology and strong topology?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

As the title suggests I am trying to find out, what the difference of the weak topology $\tau_\omega$ and the strong topology $\tau$ explicitly is.

The setup is the following.

> We are given a normed vector space $(X, ||\cdot||)$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Denote by $\tau$ the strong topology, i.e. the topology induced by the norm $||\cdot||$. Now we define the weak topology to be the smallest topology generated by the sets $\Omega_{l,U} := l^{-1}(U), l \in X^*=L(X,\mathbb{R}), U \subset \mathbb{R}$ open. Denote this topology by $\tau_\omega$.

My question is the following:

> Our professor said that $\tau_\omega$ and $\tau$ differ only in the case where $\dim_\mathbb{R}X = \infty$, since in that case with the sets $\Omega_{l,U}$ also every weakly open set contains a non-trivial affine subspace.
>
> Now what is an affine subspace?
>
> Why are they equal in the case where $\dim_{R}X < \infty$?
>
> And how do I understand the second part of the sentence?

Comment: I think I have an intuitive idea that weak and strong relate generality with strong theories being more general and catch all. So this sometimes means saying more or saying less. But I would wager strong topology is more general definition/theories of topology which cover more cases than a weaker one. Maybe weaker more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An affine subspace is $a+Y=\{a+y:y\in Y\}$ where $Y$ is a linear subspace of $X$.

There is exactly one topological vector space structure on a given finite dimensional real vector space.

A basis for the weak topology consists of finite intersections 
$V=\bigcap_{j=1}^n l_j^{-1}(U_j)$ with $l_j$ linear functions and $U_j$
are open subsets of $\Bbb R$. If nonempty, $V$ contains a subset $a+Y$
where $Y$ is the intersection of the kernels of the $l_j$, that is $Y$
is a vector subspace of finite codimension in $X$. So if $X$ is
infinite-dimensional every weakly open nonempty set contains an $a+Y$
with $Y$ an infinite-dimensional vector subspace. Thus an open ball
in the metric topology cannot be weakly open.

Comment: Sorry to comment this late. Looking back at your answer, how do you construct $a$?

Comment: $a$ is any element of $V$. @vaoy

Comment: ok and why does $Y$, i.e. the intersection of the kernels, have to be infinite-dimensional?

Comment: As I said, $Y$ has finite codimension. @vaoy